# javascript - Change text color with <text-shadow> effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

In `<div>` the white text has a 'text-shadow' by default.
When you click on the text it is in the color style set to `#627CA9`. I would like it to have the 'text-shadow' updated to match that same color.

```
text-shadow: 0 0 1px #FFFFFF, 0 0 2px #FFFFFF, 0 0 4px #FFFFFF;
```

I would like to add:

```
text-shadow: 0 0 1px #627CA9, 0 0 2px #627CA9, 0 0 4px #627CA9;
```

I don't know if I can put this done directly in javascript.
I would like some help on this.

Thank you in advance.
Sorry my English.

```js
function resizeIframe(obj) {
  obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}


function changeColor(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);

  if (x.style.color != "rgb(255, 255, 255)")
    x.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
  else {
    x.style.color = "#627CA9"; // forecolor
  }
}
```

```css
.centered {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Soft Press W00 Regular V1, cursive;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #FFFFFF, 0 0 2px #FFFFFF, 0 0 4px #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 80px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="changeColor('myid1'); return false;" id="myid1" class="centered">89 ROCK</div>
```

Comment: why not just toggle a class with the two rules?

Comment: yes that would be the best

Comment: `function changeColor(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle('active'); }`

Comment: thank you for your suggest @epascarello

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply make the shadow to use `currentColor` and it will automatically pick the color defined inside `color`

```js
function resizeIframe(obj) {
  obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}


function changeColor(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);

  if (x.style.color != "rgb(255, 255, 255)")
    x.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
  else {
    x.style.color = "#627CA9"; // forecolor
  }
}
```

```css
.centered {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Soft Press W00 Regular V1, cursive;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px currentColor, 0 0 2px currentColor, 0 0 4px currentColor;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 80px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
}

body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="changeColor('myid1'); return false;" id="myid1" class="centered">89 ROCK</div>
```

You can also optimize your code with a class toggle:

```js
function resizeIframe(obj) {
  obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}


function changeColor(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  x.classList.toggle('color');
}
```

```css
.centered {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Soft Press W00 Regular V1, cursive;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px currentColor, 0 0 2px currentColor, 0 0 4px currentColor;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 80px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.color {
  color:#627CA9;
}

body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="changeColor('myid1'); return false;" id="myid1" class="centered">89 ROCK</div>
```

Comment: @SergioC welcome, don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your issue

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by setting the `textShadow` field of the elements `style` object like so:

```
    element.style.textShadow = "0 0 15px #627CA9";
```

To produce an "alternating" shadow on, shadow off, behavior after multiple clicks, be sure to reset the `textShadow` style:

```
    if(shouldShadow) {
        element.style.textShadow = "0 0 15px #627CA9";
    } 
    else {
        element.style.textShadow = ""; /* Remove shadow */
    }
```

In the case of your code this would achieve what you require:

```js
function resizeIframe(obj) {
      obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
  </script>

<script>
  function changeColor(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  
  if (element.style.color != "rgb(255, 255, 255)") {
    element.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
    
    /* Reset shadow */
    element.style.textShadow = "";
  }
  else {
  
    /* Color shared for text and shadow */
    const color = "#627CA9";
  
    element.style.color = color;
        
    /* Set shadow matching color */
    element.style.textShadow = `
        0 0 1px ${color}, 
        0 0 2px ${color}, 
        0 0 4px ${color}`;
  }

}
```

```html
<div style="cursor: pointer;font-family: Soft Press W00 Regular V1, cursive;color: #FFFFFF;text-shadow: 0 0 1px #FFFFFF, 0 0 2px #FFFFFF, 0 0 4px #FFFFFF;         text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 80px;margin: 0; padding: 0;line-height: 100%;display: block;font-weight:400;" onclick="changeColor('myid1'); return false;" id="myid1" class="centered">89 ROCK</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
add this in css file 

   .forecolor_shadow{
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px #627CA9, 0 0 2px #627CA9, 0 0 4px #627CA9; 
        color:#FFFFFF;
    }

    .white_shadow{
        text-shadow: 0 0 1px #FFFFFF, 0 0 2px #FFFFFF, 0 0 4px #FFFFFF; 
        color:#627CA9;
    }

    .centered {
      cursor: pointer;
      font-family: Soft Press W00 Regular V1, cursive;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 80px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      line-height: 100%;
      display: block;
      font-weight: 400;
    }


and add this in js file 

    function changeColor(id) {
      var x = document.getElementById(id);

      if (x.classList.contains('white_shadow')){
          x.classList.remove("white_shadow");
          x.classList.add("forecolor_shadow");

      } else {
          x.classList.remove("forecolor_shadow");
          x.classList.add("white_shadow");
      }
    }

// this is the html code 

    <div onclick="changeColor('myid1'); return false;" id="myid1" class="white_shadow centered">89 ROCK</div>
```